# Magento and Stripe (without go via magento checkout) .. and Paul

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

There are a lot of **stripe extensions** for **integrate stripe gateway** into magento checkout step = OK. Or there is stripe widget for do direct payment = OK (but it, of course, if not integrated with magento can't say "Paul have bought X product").

=> How integrate Stripe buy button (widget, for direct payment in-stripe) in magento and into payment details see also product bought from Paul?? :-)
Is require import magento products in stripe database? If yes, how to do? :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To integrate the Stripe Buy Button (widget) with Magento and have the product details show up in the Stripe dashboard, you would need to use the Stripe API to create a product in Stripe with the same details as the product in Magento.

Here are the steps you can follow:

- Install the Stripe Buy Button on your Magento website: You can get the Stripe Buy Button code from the Stripe website and add it to your Magento website. This code will generate the Buy Button widget on your website.
- Use the Stripe API to create a product in Stripe: To track the product details in Stripe, you need to create a product in the Stripe dashboard with the same details as the product in Magento. You can use the Stripe API to create a product with the required details such as name, price, and description.
- Use the Stripe API to create a checkout session: Once the product is created in Stripe, you can use the Stripe API to create a checkout session. This will allow the customer to pay for the product using the Buy Button widget.
- Include the product information in the checkout session: When you create a checkout session, you can include the product information in the session data. This will ensure that the product details show up in the Stripe dashboard.
- Test the integration: After completing the above steps, test the integration by placing an order using the Buy Button widget and verifying that the product details show up in the Stripe dashboard.